# difference: at whim vs. on a whim

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

Which "whim" phrase should be used in the following?

> The boss fires people on a whim/at whim.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"On a whim" would be better for describing an individual instance of firing. "At whim" is better for a general statement about the boss's behavior.